# Marshalling an array from JAVA to XML

Tags: java, xml, marshalling

I have a list of pc parts that I can choose from, and move to the right side to create list. In the File Menu, I need to be able to save, which should marshal the contents of the rightList and save it as an XML file. I have tried everything I can think of, but nothing is working. Please help.

Here is my Window.java file with my main().

```
 package com.cooksys.assessment;

 import javax.swing.AbstractListModel;
 import javax.swing.DefaultListModel;
 import javax.swing.JButton;
 import javax.swing.JFrame;
 import javax.swing.JList;
 import javax.swing.JMenu;
 import javax.swing.JMenuBar;
 import javax.swing.JMenuItem;
 import javax.swing.JPanel;
 import javax.swing.plaf.ListUI;
 import javax.xml.bind.JAXBContext;
 import javax.xml.bind.JAXBException;
 import javax.xml.bind.Marshaller;

public class Window {

private JFrame frame;

/**
 * Launch the application. The main method is the entry point to a Java
 * application. For this assessment, you shouldn't have to add anything to
 * this.
 */
public static void main(String[] args) {
    EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            try {
                Window window = new Window();
                window.frame.setVisible(true);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    });
 }

/**
 * Create the application. This is the constructor for this Window class.
 * All of the code here will be executed as soon as a Window object is made.
 */

public Window() {
    initialize();
}

public void save() throws Exception {
    try {
    JAXBContext context = JAXBContext.newInstance(Configuration.class);
    Marshaller marshaller = context.createMarshaller();
    Configuration config = new Configuration();
    File file = new File("order.xml");
    marshaller.setProperty(Marshaller.JAXB_FORMATTED_OUTPUT, true);
    marshaller.marshal(config, System.out);
    marshaller.marshal(config, file);
 }
    catch (JAXBException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
 }


/**
 * Initialize the contents of the frame. This is where Window Builder will
 * generate its code.
 */

@SuppressWarnings({ })
public void initialize() {
    frame = new JFrame();
    frame.getContentPane().setBackground(SystemColor.controlHighlight);
    frame.setBounds(100, 100, 450, 300);
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

    JMenuBar menuBar = new JMenuBar();
    frame.setJMenuBar(menuBar);

    JMenu mnFile = new JMenu("File");
    menuBar.add(mnFile);

    JMenuItem mntmLoad = new JMenuItem("Load");
    mntmLoad.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

        }
    });
    mnFile.add(mntmLoad);


    JMenuItem mntmSave = new JMenuItem("Save");
    mntmSave.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
            try {
                save();
            }
            catch (Exception e1) {
                e1.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    });
    mnFile.add(mntmSave);

    JMenuItem mntmExit = new JMenuItem("Exit");
    mntmExit.setToolTipText("Exit application");
    mntmExit.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) {
            System.exit(0);
        }

    });
    mnFile.add(mntmExit);
    frame.getContentPane().setLayout(null);

    JPanel leftPanel = new JPanel();
    leftPanel.setBackground(Color.WHITE);
    leftPanel.setBounds(0, 0, 156, 240);
    frame.getContentPane().add(leftPanel);


    final DefaultListModel<Object> leftModel = new DefaultListModel<Object>();
    leftModel.addElement("Case");
    leftModel.addElement("Motherboard");
    leftModel.addElement("CPU");
    leftModel.addElement("GPU");
    leftModel.addElement("PSU");
    leftModel.addElement("RAM");
    leftModel.addElement("HDD");

    final JList<Object> leftList = new JList<Object>(leftModel);
    leftPanel.add(leftList);

    JPanel rightPanel = new JPanel();
    rightPanel.setBackground(Color.WHITE);
    rightPanel.setBounds(272, 0, 162, 240);
    frame.getContentPane().add(rightPanel);

    final DefaultListModel<Object> rightModel = new DefaultListModel<Object>();
    final JList<Object> config = new JList<Object>(rightModel);
    rightPanel.add(config);

    JButton addButton = new JButton(">>");
    addButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            for(Object selectedValue:leftList.getSelectedValuesList()) {
                rightModel.addElement(selectedValue);
                leftModel.removeElement(selectedValue);
            }
        }
    });
    addButton.setBounds(183, 58, 59, 23);
    frame.getContentPane().add(addButton);

    JButton removeButton = new JButton("<<");       
    removeButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            for(Object selectedValue:config.getSelectedValuesList()) {
                leftModel.addElement(selectedValue);
                rightModel.removeElement(selectedValue);
            }
        }
    });
    removeButton.setBounds(183, 123, 59, 23);
    frame.getContentPane().add(removeButton);



}
}
```

And here is the content of my Configuration.java file. Any help would be appreciated.

```
package com.cooksys.assessment;

import java.util.*;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.*;

@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.PROPERTY)
@XmlType(name = "rightList")
@XmlRootElement(name = "Configuration")
public class Configuration {

protected List<String> rightList;

public List<String> getComponents(){
    if(rightList == null){
        rightList = new ArrayList<String>();
    }
    return this.rightList;
}

public List<String> getRightList() {
    return rightList;
}

public void setRightList(List<String> rightList) {
    this.rightList = rightList;
}
}
```

Comment: What exactly is not working? Empty file? Wrong data? It's important to give potential answerers as much info as possible, to improve your chances of getting a quality answer quickly.

Comment: The XML file is not created and the output is empty. There are no errors when I run the application.

Answer (score 1):

The xml marshalling is fine but config is always empty. Move the definition of rightModel to in front of save() so that it will be accessible to the save function. Add all the elements from rightModel to a list and set the config.rightList to that list:

```
final DefaultListModel<Object> rightModel = new DefaultListModel<Object>();

public void save() throws Exception {
    try {
        JAXBContext context = JAXBContext.newInstance(Configuration.class);
        Marshaller marshaller = context.createMarshaller();
        Configuration config = new Configuration();
        List<String> l = new ArrayList<>();
        Enumeration<Object> e = rightModel.elements();
        while (e.hasMoreElements()) {
            l.add(e.nextElement().toString());
        }
        config.setRightList(l);
        File file = new File("order.xml");
        marshaller.setProperty(Marshaller.JAXB_FORMATTED_OUTPUT, true);
        marshaller.marshal(config, System.out);
        marshaller.marshal(config, file);
    } catch (JAXBException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```